# Complex function with specific residues

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus, singularity, meromorphic-functions

I am supposed to find a holomorphic function $f:\mathbb{C}\setminus \{-1,+1\} \to \mathbb{C}$ such that it has essential singularities in $-1$ and $+1$ and $res_{-1}f=-1$ and $res_{+1}f=+1$. Is this function unique by these properties? 
I can't seem to work it out with both conditions. There are different functions I tried to manipulate so that it satifies the conditions: First $\frac{1}{cosz}$ and second something like $\frac{1}{1-e^{z-1}}$. The first function has the right residue but at the wrong places (acc. to wolframalpha) and I am not even sure if they are essential singularites. I tried manipulating the period in the denominator but it always changes the value of the residue as well. On the other hand The second function already has at least the singularity $+1$ and the right value, but if I add another term for $-1$ it breaks. The $cos$ function has the advantage that I would already know, that there is some sort of sin-function with the same properties, so it wouldn't be unique. In general I think there could be moutiple functions with these properties.
Any idea how to work on this more systematically?

Comment: Try to just work with one sungularity at a time. Can you construct a function $f_1$ with just one essential singularity in $-1$ with $res_{-1}f_1=-1$? Now construct $f_2$ with an essential singularity at $1$ with $res_1 f_2=1$. What properties does $f_1+f_2$ have?

Comment: Also, your proposed solutions have two big issues: (1) Those functions have poles, not essential singularities. (2) Those functions have more than just two poles (in fact, they have infinitely many).

Comment: @C-RAM Hey, thank you for the hints. I would now take $exp(1/(z-1))$ and $exp(1/(z+1)$ each of them have the desired residue. If I look at the sum of those two functions, I see that the singularities stay essential. The only problem is that the value of the residue changes.

Comment: The values of the residues of the sum of those two functions should just be their individual redidues. The residues should definitely not change when you add them. You've definitely done something wrong, because both of those functions have residue $1$ at their singularity. Double check your method for evaluating the residues.

Comment: But by the Laurent series I get: $exp(\frac{1}{z-1}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^n \frac{(z-1)^{-k}}{k!}$ and then the residue would be -1 right? Of corse, it's still the same for the other function but mutiplying by -1 should do the trick.

Comment: Well, that's your problem (or at least part of it)... Where are you getting that $(-1)^k$ term from?

Comment: Jep, you're right. It's a lot clearer now. Took my time and did everything slowly. Thank you for your help. The function is $exp(\frac{1}{z-1})-exp(\frac{1}{z+1})$.

Comment: Nice job. Remember you can always give your own question an answer if you want, now that you've figured things out.